# Providing /bin and /lib inside a chroot jail

Tags: symlink, chroot

I need to be able to provide the /bin and /lib directories inside a chroot jail so that programs can dynamically link properly.

Is there a way to accomplish this without making a copy of the /bin and /lib dirs to the chroot jail?

I've tried symlinks, and they don't work from inside chroot jails, and directories can not be hardlinked.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You could use `mount` to remount the directories you need in your jail:

```
# mount --bind /bin /chroot/bin
# mount --bind /lib /chroot/lib
# chroot /chroot
```

For use in `/etc/fstab`:

```
/bin /chroot/bin none bind
/lib /chroot/lib none bind
```

Cheers!

Comment: Thanks a lot. Linux just keeps getting better and better the more I play with it :p

Comment: I'm glad it worked out well! Cheers!

Answer (score 3):

If you didn't want to mount the directories as jgr said, you can use `cp` to recursivly copy directories and create hardlinks for all files:

```
cp -alf /bin /chroot/bin
cp -alf /lib /chroot/lib
chroot /chroot
```

This way your chroot's `/bin` and `/lib` can have slightly different structure / contents than the main directories.

Comment: Good idea, but if the /chroot is on a different device this won't work.  You can't hardlink across devices.

Answer (score 1):

```
#!/bin/bash

copy_file_and_dependencies() {
    PROGRAM="$1"
    DEPENDENCIES="$(ldd "$PROGRAM" | awk '{ print $3 }' | grep -v '(' | grep -v 'not a dynamic executable')"

    mkdir -p "${JAIL}$(dirname $PROGRAM)"
    cp -Lv "$PROGRAM" "${JAIL}${PROGRAM}"

    for f in $DEPENDENCIES; do
        mkdir -p "${JAIL}$(dirname $f)"
        cp -Lv "$f" "${JAIL}${f}"
    done
}

export -f copy_file_and_dependencies

copy_file_and_dependencies /etc/ld.so.cache
copy_file_and_dependencies /bin/sh
# ...
```

Comment: The intent of the question seems to be to provide access to the existing files rather than copying them into the chroot.