# How to convince APT that a cross-arch package is installed manually?

Tags: debian, apt, cross-compilation, multiarch

I have a qemu-armhf chroot environment on an amd64 machine (it's mainly for compiling Raspberry Pi code).  As such it can run both armhf and amd64 binaries but it's faster doing the latter.

There are certain packages (such as make) where I've installed the amd64 version inside the chroot in order to get better speed.  That works well up until I need to apt-get some other armhf package and it happens to have make listed as a dependency, whereupon I get this:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 build-essential : Depends: make but it is not going to be installed
 dpkg-dev : Depends: make but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

If I try the suggested command, then it says it wants to install `make:armhf` and uninstall `make:amd64`.  I don't want it to do that.  How do I tell APT that `make:armhf` is already installed (because I want it to use `make:amd64` to satisfy dependencies) without actually installing it?

I've tried using `apt-mark manual make` but it says that it is not installed.

---

I know this probably isn't the right way to do it, but I've been looking at the `/var/lib/dpkg/status` file to try to work out how it thinks the package definitions work and to try to trick it into agreeing that make:amd64 satisfies make:armhf as well.

In particular I noticed that "libbz2-1.0" is a package that's listed as installed twice; once as:

```
Architecture: armhf
Multi-Arch: same
Pre-Depends: multiarch-support
```

and once as:

```
Architecture: amd64
Multi-Arch: foreign
Pre-Depends: multiarch-support
```

So I tried duplicating the entries for "make" similarly, setting all of those values above.  But now APT's just saying that "make" and "make:amd64" are conflicted.  Why is it a conflict when make does it but not when libbz2-1.0 does it?  (I hope it's not special-casing libraries; that seems like it should be a bug.)

---

Per [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/149799/78162), I tried building a dummy package with `equivs` and installing that (after removing my manual fiddling above), but installing it produces these errors:

```
# dpkg -i /var/cache/apt/archives/make_3.81-8.2_amd64.deb (real amd64 make)
# dpkg -i make_3.81-8.2_armhf.deb (fake armhf depends on the above)
Preparing to replace make 3.81-8.2 (using make_3.81-8.2_armhf.deb) ...
Unpacking replacement make ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of make:
 make depends on make:amd64 (= 3.81-8.2).
```

So again the problem looks like it thinks make:armhf is a *replacement* for make:amd64, and I don't know how to tell it that I want these two packages to coexist.  (It doesn't seem to have a problem with the idea of two libbz2 packages coexisting, for example.)

Comment: Make is a binary, multiarch won't install two binary files of different arch in same filename.  
"The existing proposals allow for the co-installation of libraries and headers for different architectures, but not (yet) binaries. So you can have either the i386 version of a binary, or the amd64 version, but not both (using conventional /bin paths)."


https://wiki.debian.org/Multiarch

Comment: That's fine, I only really want one version installed (the amd64 version).  The *problem* is that I also want to be able to install armhf library packages that depend on the armhf version of make instead of "any runnable make".  (Or to rephrase, the problem is that the libraries do not depend on "any make", they depend on "my-arch make".)

Comment: Is there something preventing you from using a cross-compile toolchain?

Comment: FWIW, I've been staying away from multiarch and using schroot, etc.

Comment: The packages I'm trying to build aren't really cross-compile-friendly; they assume they can build and run things using the same compiler for host and target.  Additionally it's convenient to use apt tools with the same repositories to ensure that I'm building against the same versions of libraries as will be installed on the target.  But as mentioned above one of the tricks that I'm trying to use to improve performance *is* to install the cross compiler as the "native" compiler inside the chroot, so it's faster.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't played much with multiarch systems, so there may well be a better way than what I'm proposing here. I haven't tested my proposal, I'm not sure that it doesn't run against some peculiarity of multiarch.

You can use [equivs](http://packages.debian.org/equivs) to [create dummy packages](https://wiki.debian.org/CreateDummyPackage) for dependencies only.

1. Create a control file with `equivs-control make.control`
2. Edit the control file: set `Package: make`, `Architecture: armhf`, `Depends: make:amd64`, and `Multi-Arch: foreign`. You may want to set `Version` to match the amd64 make version as well.
3. Create the dummy package: `equivs-build make.control`
4. Install the dummy package in the chroot

If this doesn't satisfy dpkg, a different approach that will work but is less convenient is to not install the amd64 make inside the chroot, but instead make the host root available inside the chroot (with a bind mount, see [Providing /bin and /lib inside a chroot jail](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/4897/providing-bin-and-lib-inside-a-chroot-jail) for examples), or at least the `make` binary and its dependencies (which for `make` is just libc). Add the directory where the binary is mounted to the PATH. Create a dummy package as above, but just declare `make` as installed, don't put any `Depends` or `Multi-Arch` header.

Comment: Unfortunately [this bug](https://lists.debian.org/debian-user/2012/12/msg01234.html) still seems to be a thing.  (I'm getting the same error, from an Ubuntu 14.04 host.)

Comment: wouldn't having the package depends on another package with the same name create a dependency cycle it can't satisfy?

Comment: It *ought* to be able to satisfy it, since they're different architectures.  But apparently yes, this makes it unhappy.  See my updated question.

Comment: @Miral Hmmm. Does it help if you add `Multi-Arch: foreign`
to the dummy package? But now that I think of it, the native `make` package probably needs a `Multi-Arch` field, otherwise dpkg will assume that the package doesn't support multiarch. Does your amd64 `make` package` have that header? If it doesn't, then tweaking `/var/lib/dpkg/status` would probably do the trick, but of course that's lost on upgrade. See my edit for a less convenient approach.

Answer (score 0):

This message means "if there are two different architecture packages of the same name installed, they need to be the exact same version."

This is because they both provide `/usr/share/doc/.../changelog.Debian` and a few others, and the file conflict here is okay if both install the same file.

This does not work for `make` though, because both packages provide different `/usr/bin/make`.

I believe you can use `--auto-deconfigure` to allow dpkg to set packages depending on `make` to `unpacked` (down from `installed`) state, which will cause their `postinst` to be re-run, and that allows deinstallation of `make:amd64` in favour of `make:armhf`.

Comment: That is expressly the opposite of what I wanted, though.  I wanted to keep `make:amd64` installed and have it satisfy dependencies on `make:armhf`.

Comment: That mechanism also works the other way round. Try the manual resolver in aptitude, that should give you a working configuration if one exists